# Retrofit POST error

Tags: android, retrofit

I am new to Retrofit. Have an error as response using retrofit: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

So I have to do:

--request POST

--header "Content-Type: application/json"

--data { "device": {"token": "213", "platform": "ios"} }

And I created

```
      public class Device {

            @SerializedName("token")
            @Expose
            private String token;

            @SerializedName("platform")
            @Expose
            private String platform;

            public String getToken() {
                return token;
            }

            public void setToken(String token) {
                this.token = token;
            }

            public String getPlatform() {
                return platform;
            }

            public void setPlatform(String platform) {
                this.platform = platform;
            }

        }


    public class Example {

        @SerializedName("device")
        @Expose
        private Device device;


        public Device getDevice() {
            return device;
        }

        public void setDevice(Device device) {
            this.device = device;
        }

    }


        public interface ApiService {

            @POST("/")
            void addDevice(@Body Example example, Callback<String> callback);

        }


   private void executePostDevice() {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(NetworkConstants.DEVICES_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addHeader("header", "application/json");
                    }
                });
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        Example ex = new Example();
        Device device = new Device();
        device.setToken("test_token");
        device.setPlatform("android");
        ex.setDevice(device);
        ApiService apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
        apiService.addDevice(ex, new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String s, Response response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You typed the `Callback` as a `String`, instructing the framework to deserialise the http response body to a string. Evidently, the post response is a more complex piece of (json) data, since a `BEGIN_OBJECT` was encountered.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right! Of course it is good to send back entity that was created while making POST request, but sometimes it isn't done. So how then I can read response (I thought it should be String)?

Comment: @AnastasiaRiss you can use general Object as your callback generic object and then check if Object can be casted to what ever you expect.

Comment: Yes, is works. Thanks